# Can't get the last empty line in Python

Tags: python

I just want to know if a file contains a last empty line, or not.

Here's my code:

```
lines=open(file_path).readlines()
last_line=lines[-1]
print(last_line)
if last_line.strip():
    print('has last empty line')
```

But when I run it on a file that has a last empty ending line, I get the last **two** lines in my `last_line` variable. Thus it never finds out, because the `strip()` never becomes `False`.

What should I do?

Comment: `last_line` doesn't have two lines, you probably don't really have an empty last line. Add 4 spaces in this line and save the file.

Comment: I said add spaces, not lines. Just because it looks like an empty line in the text editor it doesn't mean it really is an empty line. The missing line is represented as the `\n` in the actual last line.

Comment: @Guy, when I print it, I get two lines in the console. So it's a real empty line.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a **t.txt** file and inserted some data with an empty line at the end.

so if I print it!

**lines** give:

> ['my\n', 'test\n', 'file\n']

so the last empty line is definitely represented by **\n** because if you remove it from the file you get:

> ['my\n', 'test\n', 'file']

...without **\n** so now to detect if the **last_line** has an **\n** you can check it as below

```
lines=open("t.txt", 'r').readlines()

print(lines)
last_line=lines[-1]
print(last_line)

if '\n' in last_line:
    print('has last empty line')
```

Answer (score 0):

If "empty line" means that the line is `"\n"`:

```py
from io import SEEK_END

def ends_with_newline(file):
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        try:
            f.seek(-1, SEEK_END)
        except OSError:
            # The file contains nothing.
            return False
        return f.read(1) == b"\n"
```

If "empty line" means that the line contains only `" \t\n\r\x0b\f"`:

```py
from io import SEEK_END, SEEK_CUR

def ends_with_empty_line(file):
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        try:
            f.seek(-1, SEEK_END)
        except OSError:
            # There is no lines.
            return False

        while True:
            cur_char = f.read(1)

            if not cur_char.isspace():
                # cur_char is not empty so the last line is not empty.
                return False

            if cur_char == b"\n":
                # We reached the 2nd last line so the last line is empty.
                return True

            try:
                f.seek(-2, SEEK_CUR)
            except OSError:
                # We reached the beginning of the file so the last line is empty.
                return True
```

Comment: This means that an empty line with spaces at the end of the file would not be detected.

Comment: @Bigboy I have wrote a new function to detect spaces, tabs, etc.